# Allowing user to reply to open questions (and loop)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new to api.ai and I'm working on a VERY simple FB guided bot (bot asks question, user chooses from quick cards). Problem is, **some of my questions are open**, meaning the user can keep inputting information until they decide to move on to the next question.

**My goal is to have something like this**:

```
Bot: Hello. Please reply to this open question. 
User: This is my reply's first paragraph. However I want to keep writing. (ENTER) 
B: Anything else you would like to add? (quick button: "NO")
U: Yes, this other paragraph. (ENTER)
B: Anything else you would like to add? (quick button: "NO")
U: "NO" (Quick Button).
```

I can't figure out how to, no matter what the user writes, always give the same reply ("Anything else you would like to add?" and quick button "NO"), until the user has nothing else to say. How to keep the user in a closed loop (although a loop that is specific to that one question, as I have about 6 different ones of these).

Any advice on where to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an easy way to do this using **contexts**. It seems to work, but I will keep an eye on alternatives.

1. In the step before introducing the question, output a [context](https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-contexts), for example, `context-A`.
2. Create a new [Fallback Intent](https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-events#default-welcome-intent) (from `Intents > ...`) with `Input: context-A` and `Output: (1) context-A`. The (1) is the number of iterations. This fallback intent is the one that asks the user to write if they want to, or click the button if they are done (the button takes them to the next question, where you can repeat the process if needed).

And that's it. Basically, you are creating a new context for this question to live in, and then looping the fallback intent until the user moves to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able use parameters and @sys.any.

Intent #1: What is your answer to this question?
-> Output Context: Answering
Intent #2: Continue answering or say Done.
-> Input Context: Answering
-> Output Context: Answering
-> User says: "x" and set the entirety of their response "x" to @sys.any, catching any value as 'not done'
-> User says: "done" then move on...